# Change value of a column in a multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                        holiday  
YEAR MONTH DAY TIME
2012 10    2   00:00:00       0
               06:00:00       0    
               12:00:00       0
               18:00:00       0
2012 10    3   00:00:00       1
               06:00:00       0
               12:00:00       0
               18:00:00       0
2012 10    4   00:00:00       0
               06:00:00       0
               12:00:00       0
               18:00:00       0
```

Where the 0 mean that the day is not a holiday and 1 that it is a holiday. However, the 1 only comes in the 00:00:00 hour and I want to replace all 0's on that day to 1's.

```
                        holiday  
YEAR MONTH DAY TIME
2012 10    2   00:00:00       0
               06:00:00       0    
               12:00:00       0
               18:00:00       0
2012 10    3   00:00:00       1
               06:00:00       1
               12:00:00       1
               18:00:00       1
2012 10    4   00:00:00       0
               06:00:00       0
               12:00:00       0
               18:00:00       0
```

Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? You could at the very least provide the data in a more convenient format.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
df['holiday']=df.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).cumsum().values
```

Answer (score 2):

Groupby is a good idea:

```
# transform('any') or transform('first') also work
df['holiday'] = df.groupby(['YEAR','MONTH','DAY']).holiday.transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `reindex`

```
df.max(level=[0, 1, 2]).reindex(df.index)

                         holiday
YEAR MONTH DAY TIME             
2012 10    2   00:00:00        0
               06:00:00        0
               12:00:00        0
               18:00:00        0
           3   00:00:00        1
               06:00:00        1
               12:00:00        1
               18:00:00        1
           4   00:00:00        0
               06:00:00        0
               12:00:00        0
               18:00:00        0
```

#### Setup

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    [2012], [10], [2, 3, 4],
    pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=4, freq='6H')
], names=['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'TIME'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'holiday': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, idx)
```